# Erratic behaviour when loading new views

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have been trying for days to resolve an issue with a bug in my code but I can't figure it out.

This is my first ever iOS app and post on here so go easy on me!

Basically, I have an app that has a 'create' button and a 'load' button. When the 'create' button is pressed, its position moves and a textfield is created for the user to input text. When the 'load' button is pressed, again the position moves but a tableview is created for a user to select previous file names.

If the user presses the 'create' button, fills in the textfield, and again presses 'create', the application segues to the new view perfectly. This is the same when the user presses 'load', selects a file name from the table view and again presses 'load' to segue to the new view. They both segue to the same view and it all works perfectly.

However, if the user clicks the 'create' button (which animates the buttons and creates the textfield), and then clicks away, reverting the view to the original layout, and then decides to load a previous file (which again animates the buttons but this time creates the table view), the new view loads very bizarrely! Instead of animating from the bottom to fill up the screen, it appears halfway over the previous view, moves up slightly and then down to cover the old view.

What is even more bizarre is that the weird loading of the views continues across all views when this bug occurs.

I programmatically trigger the segues, using

```
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"First" sender:sender];
```

and

```
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Second" sender:sender];
```

And I have ensured the segues are labelled correctly.

Does anyone have a similar experience and they have managed to rectify the problem? I did try to upload pictures to show the problem better but I do not have enough points :(

I have uploaded a video to youtube of the bug which should more clearly show the issue:

http://youtu.be/rB5qpF2ImSk

Comment: Gregg, welcome to StackOverflow and good luck on your first iOS Project. Dumb question but have you actually tried to follow through and see where its going. I assume you know how to use breakpoints in the code?

Comment: @logixologist thanks for the response. I have followed through the code and it seems ok to me. It segues to the correct view, but the animation of the new view is not how it should be. I have selected cover vertical but it doesn't do this :(

Comment: There's no obvious reason for this to happen based on your explanation. I think you might need to upload this project somewhere so people can actually look at your code and controller setup.

Comment: @rdelmar I have edited my post and include a video to illustrate the issue. Maybe this will help?

Answer (score 0):

Your video demonstrates what I think your problem is. When you start out on the Meal Planner page, and segue to the next controller, it looks like you're doing a modal presentation. However, when you hit what looks like a custom back arrow, you're presenting another instance of your Meal Planner view, instead of going back to the one you came from (the current view should slide down and off the screen when you dismiss a modal view). When going backwards to a previous controller, you should only use an unwind segue, if you're using segues. The alternative, is to dismiss the controller in code using dismissViewControllerAnimate:completion:.

Comment: Many thanks for the response @rdelmar it is not something I have considered! The problem also arises when i click 'new week', decide against that and try loading a previous week. Would this be the same issue? I am thinking of implementing the unwind segue like you suggested so would that fix this issue too? Thanks!

Comment: @GreggMarsdenEvans, I'm not sure whether the unwind will fix that problem, but you should definitely use the unwind anyway. You should never go backwards with a non-unwind segue because you  will build up more and more controllers (none will be deallocated), and eventually you'll get a crash from running out of memory.